# ipywidget button with on_click utilizing async functions of fabric-sdk-py. Example to make it work?

Tags: jupyter, python-asyncio, ipywidgets

Currently I'm implementing an interface to the Hyperledger Fabric using Jupyter and fabric-sdk-py. I want to submit a transaction and/or evaluate tranactions using Button ipywidget (simple example is):

```py
def _check_id(b):
    x = await contract.evaluate_transaction('queryUnprotectedEntry', [_id_info.value], user)
_check_id_button.on_click(_check_id)
```

Of course this doesn't work since `await` is called outside of an async function. If I use `async def _check_id(b)` I get problems because `_check_id' was never awaited`.

If I use `asyncio.run` or `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete`, it doesn't work as well with `This event loop is already running`

What would be the way for a button to execute an async function using `on_click`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure currently if this is the best solution but it works. To make everything work in the beginning of the module I used:

```py
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

afterwards I'm able to use the following:

```
def _check_id(b):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(contract.evaluate_transaction('queryUnprotectedEntry', [_id_info.value], user)
_check_id_button.on_click(_check_id)
```